# jQuery Fancybox use function to cut down code

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to open a number of links from a menu and I wondered if there's a function to do this instead of writing out each one.
I'm using:

```
$("#linkID").fancybox({
'padding' : 0,
'autoScale' : false,
'transitionIn' : 'fade',
'transitionOut' : 'fade'
});
```

And I was trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function FancyBoxItemMenu(linkID){
     $("#linkID").fancybox({
     'padding' : 0,
     'autoScale' : false,
     'transitionIn' : 'fade',
     'transitionOut' : 'fade'
     });
    };
```

On the menu item (an "a" tag) I used:

```
onClick="javascript:FancyBoxItemMenu(this.value);"
```

But that doesn't seem to do it and I think I'm close, but there's something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance,
Steph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, you need to append the string, like this:

```
$("#" + linkID).fancybox({
```

And use `this.id` instead of `this.value`.

---

A better idea overall approach would be to give the links a common class, for example:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="....">Link Text</a>
```

The just use that class as the selector:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
```

Comment: Thanks a TON! I don't know why I didn't think to use a class, it was much simpler, but it works like a charm. Thank you very much. :)